# Number Bases & Ruby - What is the fastest way to increment a variable intended for a specific number base?

Tags: ruby, numbers

I'd like to be able to have a variable "num" that I can increment and have it be understood what number base its in.

For example, if num is base 7 and is equal to 66, if I do num+= 1, num should be set to 100.

One solution involves to_s and to_i, however, theres so much converting going on it doesn't seem like it would be very efficient.

```
def increment_with_base(number, base)
  number_base_ten = number.to_s.to_i(base)
  number_base_ten += 1

  number_base_ten.to_s(base).to_i
end
```

Is there something more appropriate than this?  Is it possible to tell Ruby which number base I'm using so I don't have to do so many conversions?

As I mentioned in a comment below, I'm very familiar with number bases - just not number bases in Ruby.  I actually need to display each incremented number (and I'll be incrementing a lot).

Reading this next part isn't necessary if you know the answer to the question.  However, I've added it to clarify why I'm doing what I'm doing.  No need to read what follows unless you're looking for more information.

For further information, what I'm doing is generating a set of graphs where each node only has either 0 or 1 transition.  Each node is represented by a digit, and the specific digit represents which other node there is a directed edge towards.  For example, the number 4.3.1.0 is a graph with four nodes where the first node has an edge to the fourth node, the second has an edge to the third, the third has an edge to the first, and the fourth node does not have any transition.

So if I wanted to generate all four node graphs, where each node only has one exiting edge, I'd need to count from 0.0.0.0 to 4.4.4.4.

Comment: `4.3.1.0` is technically a string identifier, not a number. Are you looking for a fast way to enumerate all such strings, or do you need the earlier numeric representation for some other purpose, too?

Comment: It doesn't make difference what base the number is in. Ruby has literal expressions for numbers in several different bases, but they are internally just numbers. After all, everything is binary on a computer. When the difference of the base matters is when you are talking about the **string representation** of the number, not the number itself. Therefore, if you are going to deal with base in any way, you would be dealing with strings, and methods like `to_s`, `to_i` are unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to enumerate in a different base, you don't need to explicitly increment:

```
BASE = 4
MAX = 100
(0..MAX).each do |x|
   puts x.to_s( BASE )
end
```

This isn't much code, and it's pretty fast. Is that suitable for requirements?

And to better match your underlying problem (as well as I understand it?)

```
NODES = 4
BASE = NODES + 1
MAX = BASE ** NODES
(0...MAX).each do |x|
   puts ("0" * NODES + x.to_s( BASE )).chars.to_a[(-NODES..-1)].join('.')
end
```

I timed the above at 0.01 seconds on my laptop. But if you try with 9 nodes, it takes much much longer (no surprise, you would be looping one billion times!)

Comment: And yes, it certainly does take a while with just a few more nodes, which is why I was trying to find a fast way to do it!  This is at least a start and better than what I had, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Bases don't matter for arithmetic. Numbers are just numbers, all bases are just slightly different ways of representing them. For example, 66<sub>7</sub> (x<sub>y</sub> means x is written in base y) is 48<sub>10</sub> and regardless of what base you think in while adding one to it, the result is always the same number: 100<sub>7</sub> = 49<sub>10</sub> = 31<sub>16</sub> = ... and so on for any other base (even the really weird ones like the golden ratio base). It's the same operation with the same result.

Just do your arithmetic on *numbers* and only worry about base when it actually matters (e.g. when rendering it for a user). Even if you need to display it after every update, you still save a couple conversions, which is not only faster but also much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: I'm very familiar with number bases, just not number bases in Ruby.

Your suggestion is actually what I'm doing, only, I have to render every number up to n in the base specified. So for base four, I actually have to print out

1
2
3
10
11
...

All the way up to n.

So that is why I'm looking for a 'good' way to increment.

Comment: So what? Doing it this way is simpler and saves several conversions.

Comment: Numbers in Ruby are "natively" in base 2 in any case, unless you are using some non-standard numeric object - even rendering Ruby integers in default base 10 is in fact a conversion, just one that is well optimised and default behaviour for Ruby and most other languages. For the OP requirements, you most likely only need non-standard rendering to strings/display, not non-standard internal representations.

Comment: Delnan, you're not understanding.  Your solution is wrong because it is not any different than what I posted in my question.  The only arithmetic I have to do is increment by one, and then print, and then increment by one, and print again, etc.  So I have to do conversion after every single incrementation because I have to print after every single incrementation - and that is exactly what I posted in my question.  I do not save any conversions because each number must be outputted.  I'm not doing any real arithmetic - I'm only incrementing by one.